# How to drag image clone after drop.?

Tags: jquery

My image is drag after rotate but I can't drag image first time when it drops.this is a code for image drag and drop."dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable" I can drag this image clone and drop on "working-area". I can't drag image clone first time after drop. but the clone is draggable after rotate and resize. this is my problem....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable').draggable({appendTo: "working-area", helper: "clone" });
  $('#working-area .rotatable').live('click', function(event) {
              test = test + 90;
              $(this).rotate({ angle: test ,  appendTo: "#working-area"}).draggable();
           });
$('#working-area .rotatable').live('mousemove', function(event) {
          $(this).resizable({appendTo: "#working-area"}).parent().draggable();});
      $( "#working-area" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: "#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                *** $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());}
        }).mousemove(function(e){
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
              $('#status2').html("X = "+ x +', '+"Y = "+ y);
          });
 });
```

Please give me a solution. and refer some code.... I'm using jquery. and language is PHP.
*** this line responsible for drag after drop.
but when resizing and rotate function is added  it will not work.

Comment: Please give us a better description of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net and http://jsbin.com are excellent tools for this.

Comment: no I don't need any tool. its a web based application. I can drag it after rotate and re size. but I can't drag it first time when I drop it on "working-area".

Comment: What he meant was that we can't solve your problem until you can post a demo for us to look at. We can't help you with your problem just by looking at the code. Go to jsfiddle.net and set up your code there and then post the link here

Comment: here is the link for .....http://jsfiddle.net/yKNKE/8/                      but I can't include some script...so, the image will not rotate,...

Answer (score 0):

drop: function( event, ui ) {
                 $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());}
        })