# How to show image clone when drag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am new to jquery. I find a code to drag a image clone and drop on a area. but when I'm dragging that image it directly append on drop region. it was not show during dragging.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $('#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable').draggable({appendTo: "working-area", helper: "clone" });

 $( "#working-area" ).droppable({ activeClass: "ui-state-default", 
                                  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                                  accept: "#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane li .rotatable",
                                  drop: function( event, ui ) 
                                        {
                                            $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());   
                                        }       
                                });
 });
});
```

please anyone help to find solution.

Comment: The `helper: clone` parameter in the draggable `init` like you have should do the trick.  Can you provide the markup or a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is the link....http://jsfiddle.net/q3zCc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was the `appendTo` of the `draggable`.  When I removed this it works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3zCc/4/

Comment: thanks it really works. but the image will drop out side the "working-area". how to prevent it.

Comment: You can add a `scope` parameter to both the draggable and droppable that connects the two: http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/q3zCc/5/

Comment: thanks again. it works.thank you so much. I have One more problem and I already post a question for that can you solve that.."My image is draggable but when I add resize and rotate function it was drag after resize or rotate but not working first time when drop. "

Comment: Having resize/rotate/drag events all on the same object can be tricky to handle since they all use the onmousedown event and it can be tricky to distinguish user intention (and ultimately how to bubble the event and which handler should be used).  You might consider using a drag handle for dragging, and have other hook points (handles) for rotate and resize.  I did not see the posted question you are referring to, comment with a link and I will take a look closer.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163307/how-to-drag-image-clone-after-drop)..this is the link of my post..and this for jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yKNKE/16/) but I can't include some script..so, its not rotate or resize.